# How do I create an object instance to use in code Visual Studio 2013 Windows Apps C#

Tags: c#, object, reference, visual-studio-2013, instance

I recently started tampering with Windows store apps. I'm having trouble referencing my objects properly. At first, when trying to automatically update a `ScrollViewer` object when a `ComboBox` object changed, I couldn't get the value of the changed index.

Using `menuDay.SelectedIndex` within my `menuDay_SelectionChanged` event caused a `System.NullReferenceException`. I fixed that by referencing my `menuDay` object as such:

`((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex`

Now, within the same `menuDay_SelectionChanged` event, I'm getting the same error when I try accessing the content of my `ScrollViewer`, `outSetList`.

I'm trying to set my ScrollViewer's content to a list of exercise activities. Too much to post. But I concatenate them using a single string.

`string += "this stuff\n"` repeat.

And then I try to set it into the ScrollViewer

`outSetList.content = string`

I get the same `System.NullReferenceException` error. It tells me that the object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

I'm pretty familiar with C#, objects, instances but nothing I've tried seems to have worked. I tried casting it, creating a variable using it as a type(`outSetlist setlist = new outSetList`) among other things.

I'm sure it's a fairly simple answer but I can't find one anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I think the xaml object are not initialized properly. Can you verify the InitializeComponent() routine is there in your constructor.

Comment: If you're working with XAML based technologies, you need to properly understand the MVVM pattern, which is the preferred way to interact with XAML UIs. Otherwise you will suffer a lot fighting the framework and trying to procedurally manipulate the Visual Tree which is a complex structure.

Comment: Basically, you don't "automatically update a ScrollViewer", nor "get the value of the changed index", or anything like that. Instead, you use proper DataBinding and create a simple class which contains the data you want to show and the logic needed to operate against the data, which is completely decoupled from the UI.